# No output but boolean is right

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I am studying for my software Engineering test and i am doing code to do the tests later. the tests are already doing what I want but I need the output too.

Can you help me understand why the output isn't working?

#### Main Class

```
import java.io.*;

public class JavaStreamTokenizerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Reader reader = new StringReader("rvew rwe");
        Tokenizer toke = new Tokenizer(reader);
        boolean result = toke.doTokenizer(toke);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

#### Tokenizer

```
import java.io.*;

public class Tokenizer {
    private final Reader reader;

    public Tokenizer(Reader reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    public boolean doTokenizer(Tokenizer readers) throws IOException {
        int intValueOfChar;
        String targetString = "";

        while ((intValueOfChar = readers.reader.read()) != -1) {
            targetString += (char) intValueOfChar;
        }
        if (targetString.length() >= 150) {
            return false;
        }
        if (targetString.equals("") || targetString.equals(" ")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(readers.reader);

            while (tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
                System.out.println(tokenizer.sval);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    public Reader getReader() {
        return reader;
    }
}
```

I really appreciate the help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you sure `result` is not empty at the point where you want to print it (`System.out.println(result);`)?

Comment: yes. it shows the result! i think the problem is in class Tokenizer

Comment: What is the "output" that you want? Are you not seeing the result of `System.out.println(tokenizer.sval);` written to the console? Please be specific.

Comment: What do you expect it to output? What is it actually outputting? How do you expect us to guess?  (Glancing at it, I suspect what it will do is slurp up all the input in the first `while` loop, then in the second `while` loop, immediately encounter EOF, return true and exit.)

Comment: And have you tried stepping through it in a debugger?

Comment: the output i am expecting in this case is: "rvew <enter> rwe" ant it should apear when i call the function doTokenizer

Comment: Yes i did, but i cant find the problem

Comment: @MiguelSousa If you had properly stepped through with a debugger, you would have seen it consume all the input before reaching the tokenizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a closer look at what this loop is doing:

```
while ((intValueOfChar = readers.reader.read()) != -1) {
    targetString += (char) intValueOfChar;
}
```

It's actually reading each character and concatenating it to `targetString`; i.e., you've read *everything*. When the second loop is called

```
while (tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
    System.out.println(tokenizer.sval);
}
```

there is nothing left to read, so it immediately evaluates to false and execution moves to the `return true` statement.

You need to reset the reader.

Comment: OP can't do as `readers` is final. Although OP can make a copy.